# Where is the variable $GOPATH set?

Tags: macos, go, environment-variables

This may be a very stupid question, but where exactly is GOPATH set?

It is not set explicitly in `.bashrc`, nor in `.bash_profile`.

But when I do: `echo $GOPATH`, I get the answer: `/Users/xxx/go`.

So, where exactly is this variable set? (I am using macos.)

Comment: have you tried to grep for it?

Comment: See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Comment: try ```cat /etc/environment```

Comment: Tried grep in bashrc and bash_profile - no luck. Tried the stackexchange answer, /etc/env* does not exist in macos. I will add macos as an additional tag in this question.

Comment: Couple of questions: Did you check whether GOPATH is being sourced from a different file from within .bashrc? Are you using a different shell like zsh ? in which case you may need to check in ~/.zshrc. Thanks